# React Native Function Component ASYNC / AWAIT Problem

Tags: react-native

sorry for bad English.

My function component not waiting API Function, I'm write async and await and not working again..

"Object are not valid as a React child" error screen...

Please help me :'/

```
const NormalCarousel = async (props) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [ResponseData, setResponseData] = useState('');

    const ComponentAPI = props.api;
    const API = await axios.get(ComponentAPI).catch((error) => {alert(error)});
    await setResponseData(API);

    return(
        <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
            {
                ResponseData.map(item => (
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.CarouselTouchable} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Ürün", {id: item.item_id})}>
                        <Image
                            style={styles.CarouselImage}
                            source={{uri: item?.item_avatar}}
                        />
                        <View style={styles.CarouselView}>
                            <Text style={styles.CarouselTitle}>{item?.item_name}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.CarouselSubtitle}>{item?.item_stock_code}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                ))
            }
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is happening because the parent component trying to render this component is actually rendering a Promise which resolves into a component. That's not possible.

You should instead call the function to load the data once on component mount (`useEffect`). You'll also need to replace `useState('')` with `useState([])` since you're trying to map over this data when rendering.

```js
const NormalCarousel = (props) => {
    const { api } = props;
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getAPI();
    }, []);

    async function getAPI() {
        const API = await axios.get(api).catch((error) => alert(error));
        setResponseData(API);
    }

    return(
        <ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
            {
                responseData.map(item => (
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.CarouselTouchable} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Ürün", {id: item.item_id})}>
                        <Image
                            style={styles.CarouselImage}
                            source={{uri: item.item_avatar}}
                        />
                        <View style={styles.CarouselView}>
                            <Text style={styles.CarouselTitle}>{item.item_name}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.CarouselSubtitle}>{item.item_stock_code}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                ))
            }
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```